# How to show panel on the click of linkbutton which is inside the Gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to show a panel on the click of a linkbutton which is located inside a gridview, Whether with javascript or codebehind.

Comment: where is the linkbutton? is it in the same row as the panel? e.g. each row has a panel and a linkbutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
showPanel = function(this){
    var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlDetails.ClientID%>");
    if (panel){
        panel.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Since you're not doing anything with it, I don't think you need to pass in a reference to the LinkButton, either.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that **Panel** is an ASP Control named Panel, the `<asp:panel ...` one.

No mater where your control is (inside or outside the grid) the procedure is always the same, you will need to hook up the `click` event to the show/hide of that panel.

Working with **Update Panels** (so you avoid doing a total postback just to load part of your page) through out the year took me away from that approach and I today simply use the Show/Hide a div, for example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" Text="Click to open" OnClientClick="showPanel(this);" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server" CssClass="panel" style="display:none;">
    <h2>
        This is a title</h2>
    <p>
        This is the description</p>
</asp:Panel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPanel(elm) {
        alert('you have clicked me');
    }
</script>
```

every time you click in that link button, it will alert you.

the `<asp:panel` is converted to a simple `<div>` so it's easy to use that, you can simple verify if the `<div>` is already open, then close it, if closed, open it.

using jQuery to facilitate the handling and the writing of javascript you would make that `ShowPanel` function as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pnlId = '#<%= pnlDetails.ClientID %>';

    function ShowPanel(elm) {


        if ($(pnlId).is("visible"))
            $(pnlId).hide();
        else
            $(pnlId).show();
    }
</script>
```

you can use the variable `elm` (element) if you want to distinguish the link button row.